# Is there a way to retrieve the revision history of your question?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a sub question in a main question that I want to ask separately, but have forgotten the exact phrasing after forgetting to paste it for safety when I cut it out.

Is there a way of retrieving it from the revision history? The accepted answer doesn't include the response to the sub question so I don't think it should be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  a post has been edited, you will see text that say something like "edited 50 min ago" underneath it.  Click it, and you will get the revision history, eg https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/105121/revisions

Comment: Don't forget to mention the grace period...